# MySQL fragmentation: Update 1 row multiple times VS update multiple rows

Tags: mysql, fragment, innodb, updates, myisam

I have the first table with 100 million rows and the second tables with 1 million rows. The first table is rarely updated, let's say updated 1 time for each row. The second table is frequently updated, let's say 100 times for each rows.

I'd like to ask which case causes more fragmentation to my table? Will the performance be obviously different? And is there a difference between MyISAM and Innodb Engine?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:
This question is a general question for my understanding. The 2 tables i mentioned above have the same structure, as below:
[image]
<sub>(source: [bestbuyings.com](http://bestbuyings.com/tablestructure.png))</sub>

Comment: Show us the table structures. This is not a easy one to answer without lots of details

Comment: @Namphibian I check this post several times but somehow only now i recognize your comment. I have added the table structure for my table. Thank you!